# How to load a 3d model in .glb file format in ThreeJS?

Tags: three.js

I have read the official documentation but it seems too incomplete.
The web browser display a black screen but not the model. In the browser console there isn't any error.

The following is the code:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load('cube.glb', function(gltf) {
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.outputColorSpace = THREE.SRGBColorSpace;

    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.add(gltf.scene);

    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    animate();
}, undefined, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

--- Edit September 22 ---

Now is showing the 3d model but all is black.

I editted the code in this way:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

const loader = new GLTFLoader();

loader.load('cube.glb', function(gltf) {
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.outputColorSpace = THREE.SRGBColorSpace;

    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    scene.add(gltf.scene);

    scene.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(5));

    const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
    scene.add(light);

    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 1000);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 0.1);
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3());
    scene.add(camera);

    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.update();

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        controls.update();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    animate();
}, undefined, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your camera is probably looking away from the object. Add:

```
camera.lookAt(new Vector3()
```

See what happens. It may be that your gltf is also at some arbitrary place in space.

Comment: Is it possible to center the object to view it wherever it were located?

Comment: The thing is it can be any scene graph in the file. You can have a hundred objects before your mesh is reached, so this becomes a bit more involved. Try adding a simple cube/sphere first to verify that everything else works. Then, you can calculate the bounding box/sphere of the geometry. (Your vertices can also be far from the origin). Try reparenting this mesh to an object with no transformation. Also, try adding orbit controls so that you can navigate the scene and inspect it.

Comment: Eg, if the sun is the center of your world, earth is at some position relative to it, and then moon is at some position relative to earth. On top of that, the moon may not be centered around zero (geometry).

Answer (score 0):

You must put `AmbientLight`:

```
const light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 );
scene.add( light );
```